# Rewriting rules in .htaccess confilcts with .htpasswd

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have one sudomain: http://demo.ikeepstudying.com/.
Under this, I have one client folder: *intowealth*.

I want to add two files:

*.htaccess* file

```
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "Administration"  
AuthUserFile /demo/intowealth/.htpasswd 
require valid-user

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^attend/(.+)/([0-9]+)(.htm)*$   /intowealth/index.html?type=$1&event_id=$2 [L]
```

and *.htpasswd* file, that is not working for URL rewrite, the error is :

[image]

If I remove

```
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "Administration"  
AuthUserFile /demo/intowealth/.htpasswd 
require valid-user
```

the URL rewrite will be working well.

But how can I keep both of them in same *.htaccess* file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
AuthType Basic  
AuthName "Administration"  
AuthUserFile {$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/demo/intowealth/.htpasswd 
require valid-user

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /intowealth/

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^attend/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)(\.htm)?$ index.html?type=$1&event_id=$2 [L]
```

Comment: actually, i searched a lot, i also tried the code you wrote , but it is not working.  btw, i am using godaddy

Comment: What URL do you enter in your browser and is is this .htaccess in DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: you can try this link with intowealth/advanced#7

Comment: I am getting a basic auth dialogue. Also looks like you need `RewriteBase` line as well. See latest edit and try it out.

Comment: Though now I suspect some other rule/code causing this? 1. Is there any other .htaccess in your system? 2. Is there any other code in this currect .htaccess 3. Is there any CMS/PHP framework in place?

Comment: YES, main domain has .htaccess,  this subdomain also has htaccess, but after removing htaccess under subdomain, it is sitll not working.

Comment: Options +ExecCGI
AddType application/x-httpd-php5-3 .htm .html .php
AddHandler x-httpd-php5-3 .htm .html .php

AuthType Basic  
AuthName "Administration"  
AuthUserFile /demo/intowealth/.htpasswd 
require valid-user

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /intowealth/

RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^attend/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)(\.htm)?$ index.html?type=$1&event_id=$2 [L]

here is all content under folder intowealth

Comment: no cms/php framework in this subdomain, but other subdomain has

Comment: Pretty late here. I will come back to this problem tomorrow morning my time.

Comment: If you rename above .htaccess do you still get redirect error while requesting `http://demo.ikeepstudying.com/intowealth/attend/seminar1/1`?

Comment: hi, you can try this link http://demo.ikeepstudying.com/intowealth2/attend/seminar1/1

Comment: intowealth/advanced#7  the problem still exists

Comment: When I clicked that link it took me to: `http://ikeepstudying.com/` but if you still notice problem then it is because of something else on your system.

Comment: got to http://ikeepstudying.com/, becuase i set ErrorDocument 404 http://ikeepstudying.com in demo.ikeepstudying.com

Comment: that means, demo.ikeepstudying.com/intowealth2/attend/seminar1/1  this link is 404 error

Comment: Yes because above `.htaccess` is for `/intowealth` and here you have `/intowealth2`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38811/discussion-between-anubhava-and-fresh-lover)